# How to run the image /container in docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I have created sample docker image. When I try to run the image it is displaying running on **`http://0.0.0.0:8000`** but it is not running actually in the localhost

How to resolve that issue?

**Here Is my docker file:**

```
     FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR C:\Users\user2\FirstDocker

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**Server.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 8000;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello Nithya\n');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "DockerApplication",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js on Docker",
  "author": "Nithya <nitikishu@gmail.com>",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.1"
  }
}
```

**when I run the image:**

**docker run nitikishu/sampledocker** 
output:

> ```
>  dockerapplication!1.0.0 start /C:usersuser2FirstDocker
>  node server.js
>  Running on http://0.0.0.0:8000
> ```

But that site is not reached in **localhost:8000**

Docker command to run an image
[image: docker command]

I have used this command to run and check the host both 8000 and 8001 is not reaching

Comment: Unless you specify a fixed port mapping when starting the container, the :8000 of the container will be assigned to a random port on the host. Check `docker ps` to see where it goes to.

Comment: docker ps gives the image port is  0.0.0.0:800->8000/tcp

Answer (score 3):

You can start your container by specifying a port mapping

> docker run -p 8001:8000 <image-name>.

Then is the port 8000 of your container mapped to the port 8001 of your local machine.

So that you can access it through localhost:8001

See also the [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#general-form) reference for more details.

Comment: You can also use `docker run -p 8000 image-name` to expose it on a random port and and afterwards use `docker port image-name` to get the port that was used.

Comment: @DanielEder indeed. but you have to use the container-name (docker port container) then.

Comment: True. That's what I meant :)

Comment: still i am getting same problem. site cannot be reached @Jehof

Comment: Yes @Jehof. I attached the command prompt image with the commands which i used to run the application

Comment: @n15 I´m not sure. But why so you use app.listen(8000, 0.0.0.0)? Normally it would be enough to call app.listen(8000). Have you tried this?

Comment: yes I agree your point @jehof. app.listen(8000) is enough . If I run with app.listen(8000) also site is not reaching in docker. But in normally without docker my project it is running.